# Как выполнить команду терминала в Руби файле

Tags: ruby

Вопрос состоит в след.:

Хотелось бы иметь один файл ( руби ) при запуске которого откроется терминал в который можно будет записать сообщение или просто запустить какую-то другую программу.

Может кто-то уже с такой задачей сталкивался...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Способов много: [раз](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-60), [два](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-spawn), [три](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-popen), [четыре](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html), [пять](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Process.html#method-c-exec) (спасибо, @Jarto), [шесть](https://github.com/enkessler/childprocess).

Answer (score 2):

+1 [пять](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Process.html#method-c-exec)

```
exec([env,] command... [,options])
```

Replaces the current process by running the given external command.

Comment: могли бы просто комментарием добавить.

Answer (score 1):

```
class String
    def pr
        puts self
        self
    end
end
# 'qwerty'.pr

class String
    def eval
        Kernel.eval self
    end
end
# '`ping ru.stackoverflow.com`'.eval.
#   encode("windows-1251").pr.force_encoding("cp866").pr
# '`ls`'.eval.pr
# '`dir`'.eval.pr
# '`ruby -v`'.eval.pr
# '`whoami`'.eval.pr
# '`echo "hello world"`'.eval.pr
# '`php --ini`'.eval.pr
# '`curl ru.stackoverflow.com`'.eval.pr
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2-Lw36EhIEg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]